# All file properties are null except Id and Name?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

After uploading a file to my mobile application's appData folder and then downloading it, if you look at the Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File properties all properties are null except the Id and Name properties. I need to know the server modified DateTime and maybe the last client modified DateTime as it could be uploaded from another device to the Google Drive app folder. How do I go about getting these properties or setting them on upload so on next download I can compare to current client file?

I have included my upload code that I am using which works perfectly for upload. I have tried setting the ModifiedTime to DateTime.UtcNow in the fileMetadata section of code but then the request.ResponseBody comes back null.

```
            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
                Name = filename,
                Parents = new List<string>()
                {
                    "appDataFolder"
                }
            };

            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = fileContent.AsMemoryStream())
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, MimeTypeLookup.GetMimeType(filename));
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }

            var file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

I expected to see a request.ResponseBody to return a Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File just like it had when uploading without any dates being set. Can anyone help with this issue? I need DateTime's so that I can compare against current local file.

Steve

Comment: be aware that GDrive lies about the date and time. It might not be what you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have specified that you only want the id field

```
request.Fields = "id";
```

try

```
request.Fields = "*";
```

This will return all the fields to you.  You can play around with it however you like to return only the data you need. You can read more about it here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#partial-response

Comment: Thank you DalmTo that was on the spot. So I have everything working in a C# test Winforms application. Now to get it working in a Xamarin.Forms  Android, iOS and UWP mobile application.

Comment: @Orgbrat Just to note that Xamarin and UWP are not supported platforms. It is definitely possible to get it working on those platforms, but it may not just work; especially when using some of the auth code.